# SYBASE cursor declare as for read only become infinitive

Tags: sap-ase

There is a simple cursor, which has 260 records. Inside the loop not only print but update some tables. There is not only code, but explanation

```sql
/*Declare cursor for read only*/
DECLARE crsr_one CURSOR FOR    
    SELECT a,b,c,d   
    FROM table_name   
    WHERE a>=100       
    for read only 

    OPEN crsr_one          /*open cursor*/    
    DECLARE @a,@b,@c,@d    /*declare loop variables*/ 

    while (1=1)            /*start while loop*/    
    BEGIN    
        FETCH crsr_one into @a,@b,@c,@d    /*fetch into  variable */

        IF (@@sqlstatus = 2)               /*Break if no more records*/
            break
        /*some other code with select and update table*/   
        print "%1! %2! %3! %4!", @a,@b,@c,@d   /*Print variables*/
    END
```

The problem is:
In the while loop it became infinitive and brings the same data.

Any idea why and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good (except that the syntax for the DECLARE is invalid).
If the loop doesn't break on @@sqlstatus = 2, then the obvious question is: what value *does* it have? It can also be '1', indicating an error. To find out, print the value.
To be fully correct you should therefor also test for @@sqlstatus = 1. The easiest way to do this is to test for @@sqlstatus != 0 which covers both values 1 and 2.